# Why does downgrading Flutter App causes Data loss?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, sembast

**The Problem:**

I have an app that uses `sembast` and `shared_preferences` to store data.

Recently I Accidently Downgraded my app which caused it to lose all data stored.

I tested it in both physical as well as Emulator device both result in the same issue.
is there a way to fix this?

Note: By "fix this" I mean to prevent further data loss in case of downgading not the recovery of the lost data)

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1)Create a project

2)Store data in shared -references or sembast

3)Hot restart

4)Change build number to a lower number than the previous build (Ex: 1.0.0+110 to  1.0.0+109)

5)Hot restart

**Pubspec.yaml**

```
version: 1.0.0+111

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.9.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  excel: ^2.0.0-null-safety-3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  permission_handler: ^8.1.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  sembast: ^3.1.0+2
  sembast_web: ^2.0.0+2 #remove web version not being used
  intl: ^0.17.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  firebase_analytics: ^8.1.2
  firebase_performance: ^0.7.0+5
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.0.6
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  get_it: ^7.1.3
  open_file: ^3.2.1
  flutter_bloc: ^7.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2 #remove and maybe use cloud functions
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^19.1.69+1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  file_picker: ^3.0.3
  flutter_typeahead: ^3.1.3
  purchases_flutter: ^3.3.0
  device_info_plus: ^2.0.1
```

**Flutter Doctor:**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1081], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.2 at D:\Applications\flutter
    • Framework revision d79295af24 (2 weeks ago), 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 91c9fc8fe0
    • Dart version 2.13.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at D:\Applications\Android-SDK
    • Platform android-S, build-tools 31.0.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: D:\Applications\Android_studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at D:\Applications\Android_studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.37

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Sounds like a good design to me!  People can't downgrade software in the field for mobile, so if it's rolling back, the shared prefs can't possibly be necessarily understood or useful, and must be happening in debugging.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz it's happening in both debug as well as the release (using sign in keys) mode but I haven't tried it with google play.